# How can I call a Subclass object from a Superclass and is there a better way to do this? (Python 3)

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, oop

I am creating a game in python(3) and I have a main class with the game loop and a bunch of variables in it. I have a subclass of this to create "path" objects, and I need the variables from the main class. I also need to call the subclass from the main, superclass. Every time I call the subclass, it also calls the main classes **init** method to pass variables through. The problem is when this happens, it resets the values of all my variables in the main class.

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        foo = 0 
        sub1 = Sub()

    def foo_edit(self):
        self.foo += 5

    def main(self):
        sub2 = Sub()


class Sub(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sub, self).__init__()
        self.bar = 0

    def foo_edit(self):
        self.foo += 10
```

I've looked at many other similar questions, but none have given me the answer I need. I tried sub1 in my code(in the **init** function of main) and this creates a recursion loop error because the **init** functions call eachother forever. When I call it in the gameloop(or main in this example) it re initializes Main each time it is called, wiping the variables needed in Sub. Before I only had one instance of the "path" so I had no need of class, and had a function. Now that I need multiple "path" objects I am using a subclass of main to get the variables I need.

A solution to this problem that does or does not answer my question(calling a subclass from a superclass might be a bad idea) would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I could pass the variables needed into the "Sub" class, however I need them to be updated so I would need some sort of update method to make sure the variables passed in are changed in Sub when they are in Main. This is easily doable, but I was wondering if there was easier/better way to do it.

Comment: What's the purpose in inheriting from `Main`? Given it has the name `Main`, it implies that it the main program, and it makes no sense to have two "main" programs.

Comment: @BryanOakley It isn't two main programs, in my game I had a function for making paths, now I want to make x amount of paths so I made a path class so I can make x objects of the path class. It requires variables from the main class to do the calculations so that's why it inherits from main.

Comment: Your example is hard to understand, because neither class actually does anything.  You say you need `sub` but your class doesn't do anything with it.  Why does your class need an instance of a subclass of itself?  If every instance of `Main` needs an instance of `Sub`, and `Sub` is an instance of `Main`, then you're saying every instance of `Sub` needs an instance of `Sub`, which is recursive even just conceptually.  If `Sub` "requires variables from the main class", that doesn't mean you need `Sub` to inherit from `Main`; you could just have the `Main` instance pass itself to a `Sub` method.

Comment: Talk about code smell... You don't have to pass each main attribute as a parameter... maybe try passing a `Main` instance to your `Sub` instead of inheriting from `Main.` Inside your `Main` class, you could even have `sub1 = Sub(self)`. You can then use that instance in your `Sub`'s logic to create your paths. This is a classic case of inheritance being used where object composition is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of subclasses. Inheritance isn't for sharing data, it's for making special cases of a general type.

If `Sub` should be exactly like `Main` with a few specializations then you should use inheritance. When you say that "Sub" is a subclass of "Main", you are saying "Sub is a Main', not "Sub uses part of Main".

If `Sub` merely needs access to data in `Main`, use composition. If `Sub` needs data from `Main`, pass an instance of `Main` to `Sub`, and have `Sub` operate on the instance.

For example:

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 42
        self.sub1 = Sub(self)
        self.sub1.foo_edit()
    ...

class Sub():
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main

    def foo_edit(self):
        self.main.foo += 10
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I'm new to object orienting so I don't fully understand the concept. I knew that subclasses inherited methods and variables from the parent class, and from my limited knowledge, that seemed like the best way to pass the variables to another class.

Comment: I have one question about this solution. If a variable from Main changes after a Sub object is created, will it be updated in the Sub class? Will the current state of Main be reflected in the Sub class?

Comment: @TheTesseract'sShadow: it won't be updated in the Sub class because it doesn't exist in the Sub class. It exists in the Main class, and anything that has a reference to the Main class has a reference to the changed value. So the change will be _visible_ in the Sub class, rather than be _in_ the Sub class.